# installing Brain Scaffold Builder with broken rtree dependency

Tags: python, r-tree, nest-simulator

I have recently installed NEST on my MAC. I have to install the Brain Scaffold Builder. I followed the instructions and wrote `bsb==3.6.0b6` and I received the following error message

```
Using cached bsb-3.6.0b6-py3-none-any.whl (189 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rtree-linux==0.9.4 (from bsb)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for rtree-linux==0.9.4
```

Could you please help me to fix it?

Comment: Try `pip install bsb==3.6.0b8` instead. There was an issue with the wheel distribution of `rtree` before version `0.9.6` which the BSB depended upon. Feel free to open an issue on https://github.com/dbbs-lab/bsb if this does not fix your problem!

Comment: Still does not work. I obtain the following error message ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rtree-linux>=0.9.4 (from bsb)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for rtree-linux>=0.9.4

Comment: You need to install rtree-linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`rtree` package](https://github.com/Toblerity/rtree) did not come packaged with wheels before version 0.9.6 (see [PR#163](https://github.com/Toblerity/rtree/pull/163)) and the BSB instead published it's own version of the wheels under the name `rtree-linux` as it only contained Linux wheels and later Windows wheels. Mac wheels had never been available up until PR#163 a month ago or so.

You can resolve this issue by either cloning the repository and adapting `setup.py` to install `rtree>=0.9.7` or by asking the maintainer (disclaimer: me) to do so; I have done so and you should be able to install the BSB with version 3.6.1 (`pip install bsb`) as of now on Mac without special efforts and it will use the `rtree==0.9.7` Mac wheels.